# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in .bash_profile

Tags: unix, bash

I'm getting a syntax error when I try to create this function in my `.bash_profile`:

```
linkrepo () { ln -s "~/My/Path/$1"; }
```

I'm using Sublime Text 3 to edit this function/profile.

I have also tried:

```
linkrepo() { ln -s "~/My/Path/$1"; }
linkrepo ( ) { ln -s "~/My/Path/$1"; }
linkrepo () { ln -s ~/My/Path/$1; }
linkrepo() { ln -s ~/My/Path/"$1"}
```

And every variation of these. I always get this error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: try ending the command in the block with ;, like this: linkrepo () { ls -l ""; }

Comment: @DamjanDimitrioski I already tried to end the command with a semicolon. 4 of my examples have one.

Comment: I got bash 4.3.11(1), and this linkrepo () { ln -s "~/tmp/$1" "~/bla"; } works in my shell, both shell tested and written in ~/.bashrc profile.

Comment: in fact, just your 4-th example doesn't work.

Comment: @DamjanDimitrioski I'm using `.bash_profile`, does that make a difference?

Comment: well, try writing this inside bash_profile, before your function declaration: echo $SHELL, with this you will know if .bash_profile is using bash, sh, zsh or anything else.

Comment: sorry, echo $SHELL > ~/test_out.txt

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was with the version of bash I was using. I was on 3.2.57. Once I updated to 4.3.42(1)-release, I was able to use:

```
linkrepo () { ln -s "~/my/path/$1"; }
```

Comment: how did you check your bash version?

Comment: @stevek using `bash -v`

Comment: According to the [man page](https://manpage.me/?q=bash), the `-v` flag is for verbose, not version. To check version run `bash --version`